# Parenting object moves it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, parent, rigify

So I have these shoe laces that are already parented to the shoes, but when I try and parent it to my rig it moves it? Why is this?

[image]

[image]

It moves the laces?

[image]

Comment: what did u parent to the rig? the shoes or the laces? objects can only have 1 parent. if u parent the laces to the rig, its previous parent to shoes is lost.

Comment: Maybe unparent before (Alt P > Clear and Keep Transformations)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I had the laces parented to the shoes, so how would I keep them parented and also be able to pose the shoes while keeping the laces parented?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment your laces are parented to the shoe objects. If you want to parent them to the bones you first need to unparent them (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) with the *Clear and Keep Transformation* option, otherwise they will jump to their original location.

[image]